# ImageMagick option to set variable name/override defaults when exporting a C-style header

Tags: imagemagick

I have a feeling the answer to this is just going to be "No.", and I know I can just change the content of a generated header file after generation (EG: with awk); but I'm wondering if there's an existing option or method to change the "MagickImage" variable name to something else during conversion to a C-style header. The only C-style header option I can really find is `-define h:format=` (as documented here: https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php).

Specifically, a command like `convert rgba.png -define h:format=RGBA rgba.h` will yield output like this:

```c
/*
  rgba.h (RGBA).
*/
static const unsigned char
  MagickImage[] =
  {
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE4, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE4, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE4, 
...
```

I'm wondering if there's a built-in option to change that which I've overlooked.

*Bonus: If there's a way to prevent it from generating or setting the comment at the top that could be nice too.

※ I realize this question is kind of useless because awk exists, I'm just curious to know if these options already exist to save a few lines before I put together a batch-conversion script.

Comment: Sorry, that's [hard-coded](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/main/coders/magick.c#L13298). Piping the output through `awk` is the way to go.

Comment: @emcconville If you convert that comment to an answer I would happily accept it. Wish I could give you an extra upvote for the actual link to the source location.